# Currency x not found

Tags: magento-1.7, store-view, currency

I have created a Magento site using an English locale for the default store view in the default store. I want to have a Mongolian store view as well.

I created the store view and configured it to have `Default Display Currency: Mongolian Tugrik` and `Allowed Currencies: Mongolian Tungrik`. The Default Config has `Base Currency/Default Display Currency/Allowed Currencies: USD`. I also set the Locale to Mongolian (General->Locale Options). I have downloaded the Mongolian locale "Package" found [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/list/59) and placed all the files in the right place (I'm not sure what the Translation Methods are for in the link and how to utilize them). I added this Mongolian locale code to /app/etc/config.xml:

```
    <general>
        <locale>
            <code>en_US</code>
            <timezone>America/Los_Angeles</timezone>
        </locale>
        <locale>
            <code>mn_MN</code>
            <timezone>America/Los_Angeles</timezone>
        </locale>
    </general>
```

I have created products in the default English store view, and when I try to switch to the Mongolian view when editing a product the site crashes and logs:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:24:"Currency 'USD' not found";i:1;s:3725:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Directory\Model\Currency.php(233): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->currency('USD')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Directory\Model\Currency.php(238): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatTxt(0)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Locale.php(682): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->getOutputFormat()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Tax\Helper\Data.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->getJsPriceFormat()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\js.phtml(44): Mage_Tax_Helper_Data->getPriceFormat(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Store))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('js', true)
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page.phtml(82): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('js')
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Catalog\ProductController.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->editAction()
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\index.php(87): Mage::run('mongolian', 'store')
#29 {main}";s:3:"url";s:103:"/mc/index.php/mcadmin/catalog_product/edit/store/2/id/1/key/cd594f97cd6eb01d568839a9def93865/";s:11:"script_name";s:23:"/mc/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

When I try to view the product page on the frontend, I get the same `Currency 'MNT' not found` with a similar trace (I can show that too if needed). Both cases work fine when viewing in the English store view.

I'm not sure what is wrong or how to fix these errors. Has anyone come across this and/or knows what the problem is? Do I need to make any changes to the database to add a new language store view?

**Update:** After reconfiguring the store views per speaking with Marius, I am still having errors on the same pages...
On product edit page Mongolian store view:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:24:"Currency 'USD' not found";i:1;s:3725:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Directory\Model\Currency.php(233): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->currency('USD')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Directory\Model\Currency.php(238): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatTxt(0)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Locale.php(682): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->getOutputFormat()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Tax\Helper\Data.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->getJsPriceFormat()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\js.phtml(44): Mage_Tax_Helper_Data->getPriceFormat(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Store))
```

On product view page Mongolian store view:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:24:"Currency 'MNT' not found";i:1;s:3769:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Directory\Model\Currency.php(233): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->currency('MNT')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Directory\Model\Currency.php(238): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatTxt(0)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Locale.php(682): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->getOutputFormat()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View.php(168): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->getJsPriceFormat()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mc\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml(37): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View->getJsonConfig()
```

Answer (score 1):

*Not a valid answer, though I will leave it up as a reference*

I believe the problem was that you cannot have multiple currencies running under one website. Like my example, having an English (USD) store view and a Mongolian (MNT) store view under the same store and website. Seems like you need to have a separate website for each currency you wish to incorporate.

It makes sense, but I would think that Magento would either not allow you to implement multiple currencies under website, or at least give you some kind of warning. I couldn't find this explicitly mentioned in magentocommerce.com tutorials. However, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9738660/550309); and so I made the website and all stores and store views MNT and the errors went bye bye~

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea what the problem is, but I'm 100% sure you can have multiple currencies on one website.

Comment: So the answer I linked to is mistaken?

Comment: @Marius Could you tell me the steps to set this up, or point me somewhere?

Comment: I would say yes...it's wrong. Here is a website on which I worked some time ago and it has 2 currencies on the same website (GBP & EUR): http://www.bambinoworld.co.uk/. I will try to set up a website like you did and if I find an answer I will post it here

Comment: @Marius That would be great! Even posting the steps involved would be very helpful, I can rework it and maybe see where I slipped.

Comment: @Marius I had a couple questions about how you setup your GBP & EUR if that's cool. I made a chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8998/multi-langual-multi-currency-website-in-magento